# PHP - Use same array value in the same array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a long array such as:

```
$userLogs = array(
    'report-abuse-key' => array(
        'name' => null,
        'path' => null,
        'code' => 'report-abuse-page',
        'header' => 'Would you like to proceed?',
        'link-in-navigation-menu'=>null,
        'navigation-menu-in-page'=>'Show',
        'meta'=>array(
            'show'=>null,
            'title'=>'//GET HEADER VALUE HERE//',
            'description'=>null,
            'keywords'=>null,
            'refresh'=>null,
            'canonical'=>null,
            'noindex-tag'=>'Show',//'null' = Do SEO; 'Show' = No SEO;  
            ),
        ),
);
```

I would like to get the value from `$userLogs['header']` and have it duplicated in `$userLogs['meta']['title']` i.e. I want it to have it replicated and update automatically without using copy/paste.

Comment: can't you assign `'title' => $userLogs['header'],` directly?

Comment: Hi. It doesn't work.

Comment: can you write your code part, what have you implemented to achieve this so far?

Comment: Hi, its above... Its the array. I want to replicate `'header' => 'Would you like to proceed?',` in 'title'=>'//GET HEADER VALUE HERE//',

Comment: you have to explain what are you trying to do, your question doesn't sound logical, it may be [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [php reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php). You need to assign the reference of your `header` variable to the `title` variable. After this the `title` value will have reference to `header` . Any update in `header` will update the `title` as well

```
<?php
$userLogs = array(
    'report-abuse-key' => array(
        'name' => null,
        'path' => null,
        'code' => 'report-abuse-page',
        'header' => 'Would you like to proceed?',
        'link-in-navigation-menu'=>null,
        'navigation-menu-in-page'=>'Show',
        'meta'=>array(
            'show'=>null,
            'title'=>'//GET HEADER VALUE HERE//',
            'description'=>null,
            'keywords'=>null,
            'refresh'=>null,
            'canonical'=>null,
            'noindex-tag'=>'Show',//'null' = Do SEO; 'Show' = No SEO;  
            ),
        ),
);

$userLogs['report-abuse-key']['meta']['title'] = &$userLogs['report-abuse-key']['header'];

$userLogs['report-abuse-key']['meta']['title'] = 'Updated';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($userLogs);exit;
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [report-abuse-key] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [path] => 
            [code] => report-abuse-page
            [header] => Updated
            [link-in-navigation-menu] => 
            [navigation-menu-in-page] => Show
            [meta] => Array
                (
                    [show] => 
                    [title] => Updated
                    [description] => 
                    [keywords] => 
                    [refresh] => 
                    [canonical] => 
                    [noindex-tag] => Show
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Better to add results of `print_r`.

Comment: @ImranZahoor Added the result set as well. Thanks